# Larger simulation of adding and removing items from queue in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, queue

My friend got the next test assignment. Implement a class Item as part of a larger simulation of adding and removing items from queue.

The add method adds the number at the end of queue, get method removes first number from the queue and returns it.

```
class Item
{
    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function add($number){
    }

    public function get(){
    }
}
```

We tried everything that came to our mind, but the execution time does not fall below 15sec for 50.000 iterations. Does anyone know a better solution to this problem?

Test case:

```
$n = 50000;

for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
    $item->add("Test".$i);
}

for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
    echo $item->get()."\n";
}
```

Here's what we've tried:

**With array_shift:**

```
$this->numbers[] = $number;
return array_shift($this->numbers);
```

times elapsed in secs: 
22.661945819855 | 
23.122117042542 | 
21.985857009888 | 
22.498090982437

**array_shift and array_push:**

```
array_push($this->numbers, $number);
return array_shift($this->numbers);
```

times elapsed in secs: 25.500070095062 |
 22.558148860931 |
 21.946757078171 |
 22.031461000443

**unset:**

```
    array_push($this->numbers, $number);
    $key = key($this->numbers);
    $n = $this->numbers[$key];
    unset($this->numbers[$key]);
    return $n;
```

times elapsed in secs: 18.401049852371 |
 14.445369958878 |
 15.184392929077 |
 16.063473939896

**array_splice:**

```
    array_push($this->numbers, $number);
    $key = key($this->numbers);
    $n = $this->numbers[$key];
    array_splice($this->numbers, $key, 1);
    return $n;
```

times elapsed in secs: 49.540771007538 |
 47.315555810928 |
 46.451086997986 |
 46.475464820862

**SplDoublyLinkedList:**

```
    $this->numbers = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
    $this->numbers->push($passportNumber);
    return $this->numbers->shift();
```

times elapsed in secs: 18.166617155075 |
 17.268024921417 |
 15.621854066849 |
 18.711433887482

**Linked lists:**

```
class ListNode
{
    public $data;
    public $next;
    function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        $this->next = NULL;
    }
}

class Item
{
    $this->firstNode = null;
    $this->lastNode = null;
    public function add($number)
    {
        $link = new ListNode($number);

        if ($this->firstNode === null) {
            $this->firstNode = &$link;
            $this->lastNode = &$link;
        } else {
            $this->lastNode->next = &$link;
            $this->lastNode = &$link;
        }
    }

    public function get()
    {
        if ($this->firstNode === null) {
            return null;
        }

        $n = $this->firstNode->data;
        $this->firstNode = $this->firstNode->next;

        return $n;
    }
}
```

times elapsed in secs: 19.694635868073 |
 17.934485912323 |
 18.973595142365 |
 18.013978004456

Comment: what php version are you using and what is your pc config:) 'cause with the array_shift implementation I've got this result for add and get - 0.044579982757568
3.9010820388794

Comment: PHP 7.1.16 on Macbook Pro 2011, i5, 8GB RAM. We also get that result when nothing is printed. If method get returns the number that is removed from the list and echo/print then the time increases.

Comment: yeah, of course the get method is the heaviest one - cause array_shift is fat method. u can improve it as to use array_slice on 1000 elements for example. I'll try to solve it now

Answer (score 0):

the main part the time is taken on is the get method and it's array_shift. you can use array_slice instead on 1000 elements for example:

```
<?php
class Item
{
    protected $numbers = [];

    public function add($number){
        $this->numbers[$number] = true;
    }

    public function get(){
        $x = key($this->numbers);
        unset($this->numbers[$x]);
        return $x;
    }
}

ob_start();

$n = 50000;
$item = new Item();

$start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
    $item->add("Test".$i);
}

echo microtime(true)-$start;
echo "\r\n";
$start = microtime(true);

for ($i=0; $i < $n ; $i++) { 
    echo $item->get() . "\r\n";
}

echo microtime(true)-$start;

ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Yes, that is correct 0.082641124725342, 0.18116903305054. But you forgot to print the numbers. When you change  to echo $item->get()."\n", execution time is 14.767911911011.

Comment: A small note, every time the number is requested, it is necessary to remove it from the queue.

Comment: are you running it via cli or via browser? I suppose that 14 extra seconds come from the tcp the data is transferred by when you use browser :)

Comment: I am running it from cli.

Comment: so, I've updated the post - can you test again pls? cause for me it was always fast:)

Comment: Execution time is 17.190821886063 as I wrote :(

Comment: so, the problem is with the echo. is there smth more about your environment? docker or smth else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183956/discussion-between-myxaxa-and-majklrs).